# Ayuda con crear un registro php e insertar en database

Tags: php, android, mysql, base-de-datos

No entiendo mucho sobre esto, pero lo que estoy haciendo es un proyecto de android.

Cree un login con facebook, que lleva a un registro de usuarios, en lo que solo los usuarios ingresan un usuario, y el resto de datos los sustraigo del perfil.

La función que cree se llama `functions.php` que es el siguiente archivo.

```
<?php 
header( 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' );


function ejecutarSQLCommand($commando){

  $mysqli = new mysqli("*******", "*******", "*******", "******");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
     if ($resultset = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

        }
        $resultset->free();
     }


}



$mysqli->close();
}

function getSQLResultSet($commando){


  $mysqli = new mysqli("******", "*******", "*******", "******");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
    return $mysqli->store_result();




}



$mysqli->close();
}


?>
```

Y después cree este archivo llamado `registro.php`

```
<?php include ('functions.php');
$nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
$usuario=$_GET['usuario'];
$mail=$_GET['mail'];
$facebookid=$_GET['facebookid'];


ejecutarSQLCommand("INSERT INTO  `usuarios` (nombre, usuario, mail, facebookid)
VALUES (
'$nombre' ,
'$usuario' ,
'$mail' ,
'$facebookid')

 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `nombre`= '$nombre',
`usuario`='$usuario',
`mail`='$mail',
`facebookid`='$facebookid';");

 ?>
```

El tema es que yo cuando escribo el url ej:

midominio.com/carpeta/registro.php?nombre=culo suelto&usuario=matraca&mail=luigi@jimail.com&facebookid=254453

se envía a la base de datos, pero se crean muchos registros.

[image: esto es lo que se me almacenaba, fueron solo 4 intentos de enviar el registro]

Después del 3 intento me dí cuenta de un error del faecbookid y me pudo llegar una columna completa, pero eso no resolvio el problema de que se creaban muchas tablas.
si me podrían corregir los .php se los agradecería!! y si me explican como puedo borrar todos esos registros fallidos, o la tabla también se los ¡agradecería!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu archivo functions.php en donde dice **if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {** reemplaza por:

```
if ( $mysqli->query($commando)) {
```

Para eliminar todos los registros de tu tabla usuarios:

```
Delete FROM usuarios;
```

Para eliminar tu tabla usuarios:

```
DROP TABLE usuarios;
```

Ya te va a insertar un registro a la vez por llamada GET. Te recomendaría que tengas una función de conexión general para no estar copiando por cada función que estés utilizando.

Comment: gracias! pude borrar los registros, pero acabo de remplazar esa linea, intente nuevamente  se me generaron 3 registros

Comment: Que raro. Seguro que hiciste solo una petición? ?borra de nuevo y proba

Comment: Perdón! era un problema de mi explorador, se ve que mientras escribía la url se iba enviando de a poco

Comment: Perfecto. Que surte que se soluciono